# Fine Uploader Basic To S3

Tags: fine-uploader

Does anyone know if Fine Uploader supports it's `uploaderType: 'basic'` mode in conjunction with an S3 endpoint?

Their documentation is a box of christmas lights and I can't make heads or tails about which options work with which versions of the uploader.

Using this code, and **not** including the `#qq-template` they provide, I get the error below:

```
var uploader = new qq.s3.FineUploader({
    uploaderType: 'basic',
    element: document.getElementById("fineUploader"),
    request: {
        endpoint: "mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com",
        accessKey: "MY_AWS_PUBLIC_ACCESS_KEY"
    },
    signature: {
        endpoint: "/s3/signtureHandler"
    },
    uploadSuccess: {
        endpoint: "success.html"
    }
});
```

`Error: Cannot find template script at ID 'qq-template'!`

However, according to their docs ([Fine Uploader Getting Started](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/quickstart/01-getting-started.html)) it seems as though this is the correct way to get rid of the UI and handle that myself. Except it doesn't work.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing the jQuery plug-in workflow with the no-dependency workflow.  Just like the traditional endpoint handler, you simply need to make use of the `FineUploaderBasic` constructor.  As the documentation illustrates, all S3 endpoint handler modules are appropriately namespaced:

`var uploader = new qq.s3.FineUploaderBasic({...`

Fine Uploader supports a wide variety of workflow, endpoints, and features.  It's tough to fit that all into the documentation in a way that is intuitive for 100% of our users.  However, for the most part, the current setup has been well received.  If you have a specific suggestion for improvement, please open up an issue in the GitHub project's issue tracker.  We will soon make it [easier for users to edit the documentation as well](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/1154).